# Update data to mongoBD failed at updatedAt in laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I am doing update function to mongoDB in laravel. And I get some errors like this.
For example I have 1 table in mongoBD which is `products`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3a80d6d50c7d6f1a15b582"),
    "status" : 1,
    "name" : "Product 1",
    "slug" : "product-1",
    "description": 'test product 1',
    "createdAt" : 1658905822,
    "updatedAt" : 1659407411
    
}
```

**In controller :**

```
use App\Models\Product;
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $reqProduct = $request->data;
    // dd($reqProduct) result : 
    // array(65) {
    //     ["_id"]=>
    //         string(24) "5e3a80d6d50c7d6f1a15b582"
    //     ["status"]=>
    //         int(1) 1
    //     ["name"]=>
    //         string(11) "Product 1"
    //     ["slug"]=>
    //         string(11) "product-1"
    //     ["description"]=>
    //         string(5) "sss"
    //     ["createdAt"]=>
    //         string(10) "1658905822"
    //     ["updatedAt"]=>
    //         string(10) "1678537691"
    // }
    $product = Product::where('_id', '=', $reqProduct['_id'])->first();
    $product->update($reqProduct);
}
```

So the update was successful. But my database sometimes come up with a case, `updatedAt` when saving in int type, but sometimes it is stored in date type (ISODate).

**Example :**

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3a80d6d50c7d6f1a15b582"),
    "status" : 1,
    "name" : "Product 1",
    "slug" : "product-1",
    "description": 'test product 1',
    "createdAt" : 1658905822,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    
}
```

And when I click update the error message: `Object of class Carbon\\Carbon could not be converted to int`.

I tried :

```
    $product = Product::where('_id', '=', $reqProduct['_id'])->first();
    $product->unset('updatedAt', $product->updatedAt);
    $product->update($reqProduct);
```

But can't. Everyone please give me the solution so I can fix it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert it to datetime string before updating.

```
$updated_at = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1678537691)->toDateTimeString();
["updatedAt"] => $updated_at,
```

Comment: My updatedAt always saves as an int. But there are only some cases, for which I don't know the reason, it's stored as date. So error.. now how to convert that date type to int type and then save the new one in the database like that